# How to fix flask.cli.NoAppException when running flask server

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently taking CS50's Web Programming with Python and JavaScript class. I am trying to run a flask server however I am getting flask.cli.NoAppException error. I am trying to connect to a postGRES SQL database on heroku.

- Running Mac OX Mojave version 10.14.4 and using bash command line
- Able to connect to Adminer tool for project
- Able to connect to heroku and View Credentials to obtain URI for flask 
  environment
- Confirmed all required packages are installed with pip3 install -r v 
  requirements.txt
- Tried using home-brew to update SSL
- Tried Uninstalling psycopg2 library and installing psycopg2-binary library 
  with pip

```py
import os

from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set!!!")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Project 1: TODO"
```

Bash Command Prompt:

```
Stephens-MacBook-Pro:Project1 stephen$ export FLASK_APP=application.py
Stephens-MacBook-Pro:Project1 stephen$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
Stephens-MacBook-Pro:Project1 stephen$ export DATABASE_URL="postgres://qipeqvvmvvcoqf:1c6aaa3504a58aa2b9be46b85d79a05159f5ccb1f64e3e27070a024a02c3b83e@ec2-174-129-208-118.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3lrnl0okcg99k"
Stephens-MacBook-Pro:Project1 stephen$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 334-645-143
```

When I open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ I should see the text "Project 1: TODO"!

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjMnd.png)

Comment: Please include the error *and traceback* when asking debugging questions.

Comment: I have just added the error and traceback as a screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

this happens usually when one or more packages are corrupted. try updating all packages using pip
use the following command

```
pip install -I --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```